# Git: Recognize/identify version(s) of untracked copy / match to according commit(s)

Tags: git, duplicates, git-diff

### TL;DR

For whatever reason sometimes you (at least I) end up copying a certain state of your project "outside" your repo.

Is there a way for git to compare such files to all blobs and correctly match the according commit(s)?

### Example

I have 10 commits in my project.

1. a) At commit #6 I send an archive of the project per mail
2. b1) At commit #6 for whatever reason I copy my project to an untracked
   place
3. b2) At commit #6 for whatever reason I copy my project to
   an untracked place and make changes

Months later I find the copy but don't remember if I (accidentally) made any changes on them.

Now I want to find out what commit(s) they match or if they match any of my commits at all (usually to find out whether I can delete them or not).

Ideally I can find out what commit(s) they match most and how many added, deleted and modified lines there are compared to each commit.

Can git do that by itself? Is there any other tool that's able to do that?

### Disclaimer

English is not my mother tongue, please feel free to correct/edit/restructure this question

Comment: As far as I got it `git-diff --find-copies` looks for copies either inside one state (commit/index/working tree) or between two given states (commits/...) but does not search all commits for copies of (a) file(s)

Comment: In order just to find identical copies of each files might `git grep`ing each of them be a solution?

Comment: What about `git diff`ing each file to each of `git rev-list --all`?
Is there an easy way to parse and process the results und display them in a convenient format?
Maybe diffing should rather be done by an external tool in this case? Which one?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing *built in* to Git to do that.

There is a relatively easy method you can achieve with a script, by adding a new commit (or at least a tree, we don't need a commit) to your repository consisting of the archived version.  This will only work if the new tree is bit-for-bit identical to the original, both in terms of file names and contents, and permissions (executable vs not-executable).  For instance, if you left out the `.gitignore` when sending the files, the new tree won't match the actual commit that has the `.gitignore` file.

Here is a way to do it, written up as an outline:

1. create an empty temporary index
2. `git add` every file in the test tree to this temporary index
3. use `git write-tree` to write the temporary index into the repository as a tree

The output of `git write-tree` in step 3 is a tree ID.  Now you need only (only?!) visit every commit in the repository, or every commit of interest at least, and compare *its* `tree` object to the ID you just got:

```
GIT_INDEX_FILE=$(mktemp) || exit $?
export GIT_INDEX_FILE
git add ...
tree=$(git write-tree) || exit $?
git rev-list --all | while read hash; do
    commit=$(git rev-parse -q --verify $hash^{commit} 2>/dev/null) || continue
    testtree=$(git rev-parse $commit^{tree})
    if [ $testtree = $tree ]; then
        echo "test tree matches existing commit $commit"
        [ $commit != $hash ] &&
            echo "(via $hash, which is a $(git cat-file -t $hash))"
        echo git describe says: $(git describe $commit)
    fi
done
```

(this is not tested at all, and is missing some clean-up code, such as removing the temporary index).

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
If it works it actually meets the requirements I gave.
Still I'd be lucky not only to be able to find exact duplicates as in not only every single file being completely identical but also the having to have all the commit's files in the copy (in my case I only copied my `/code/` subfolder, not the `/documentation/` one)
If there's an easy way to process the results (parsing, sorting, appropriately presenting) I'd maybe go for diffing each file to each of `git rev-list --all`

Comment: If you're looking for partial or approximate matches, the task gets more difficult.  You *can* run a `git diff` against every tree and/or file, but that will take a great deal of time.  You may want to choose carefully just how much compute time you are willing to throw at the problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make the archive into a git repo.

   git init
   git add .
   git commit -m 'hello world'
   git log -1 --pretty=raw

We can get a line `tree <40-digit-sha1>`

2. Find the commit that points to the same tree in your original project.

   git log  --pretty=raw | grep -B 1 <40-digit-sha1>
3. If 2 commits point to the same tree, the 2 archives made from these 2 commits should have the same contents.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Isn't that basically the same as torek's solution except that torek avoided an extra commit?

Comment: @sqln00b Yes. `git commit` is one of Git's porcelain commands which hide the details and are more friendly to users, and @torek uses plumbing commands which are more skillful and need extra efforts to study.